# Pass paramaters from one report to another in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been stuck with this issue for quite a while so help will really be appreciated...

I have a report based on a query that shows machine utilization for a list of machines. Before loading, the report prompts dialog boxes to enter the parameters for the query: sDate and eDate (start & end dates respectively).

Each record in that report has a command button that opens another report that specifies machine errors for the single machine selected.
The new report is based on a query that receives the parameters sDate, eDate and mCode (dates and machine code).
I'm trying to send the parameters from the first report to the second one so that when I open the new report, I won't have to enter anything.
I've tried different methods to send the paramaters by editing the command button's click event in vba.

startdate enddate, machinecode are invisible textbox fields in the first report with the values I need.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_MachineBreaks", acViewReport, , "sDate=" & Me.startdate & 
" AND eDate=" & Me.enddate & " AND mCode=" & Me.machinecode
```

But the dialog boxes prompt me to enter sDate, eDate and mCode

Another approach was to modify the query parameters for the new report using QueryDefs

```
Dim db As Database
Dim qry As QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qry = db.QueryDefs("qry_singleMachineBreaks")

qry.Parameters("sDate") = Me.startdate
qry.Parameters("eDate") = Me.enddate
qry.Parameters("mCode") = Me.machinecode

DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_singleMachineBreaks", acViewReport
```

Again, the dialog boxes prompt to enter sDate, eDate and mCode...

Help Please!!!

Answer (score 1):

A common solution in Access for sharing parameters is to use a form. This allows you control of user input and can even be hidden, once the correct parameters are obtained. It is not difficult to refer to a form in a report or query:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, ADate
FROM ATable
WHERE ADate = Forms!AForm!txtDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the parameters from your underlying queries, and have your criteria defined in the `Where` clause of the `DoCmd.OpenReport`.
Another solutions is to use the `OpenArgs` param of `DoCmd.OpenReport`, and retrive that value in the OnOpen event of the report, using `Me.OpenArgs`.